Firefox uses UTC time instead of UTC+2
all of a sudden, TV program schedules were shifted by (-2) hours. Here are some relevant details on this problem:
 1. Linux Console
 
~$ timedatectl
              Local time: sam. 2024-05-04 12:41:03 CEST
          Universal time: sam. 2024-05-04 10:41:03 UTC
                RTC time: sam. 2024-05-04 10:41:03
               Time zone: Europe/Paris (CEST, +0200) System clock synchronized: yes
             NTP service: active
         RTC in local TZ: no 


Firefox-esr: Menu > Developer Tools > Console (with Time Stamp)

13:16:51,528 new Date().toString();
13:16:51,591 "Sat May 04 2024 11:16:51 GMT+0000 (temps universel coordonné) [UTC]"     
 


Firefox-esr: about:config > privacy.resistFingerprinting    = false

I don't understand why UTC+2 isn't used everywhere.
ps : I've just realized that if I open the "Settings" or "Extensions" page, the time is correct:
Date()
"Sun May 05 2024 10:06:40 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)" 


the problem solved itself when my ISP changed the address of its TV programs.

the question is: how can a single site with the wrong time zone influence all the sites open in my browser?

this quirk has just reappeared, but only for Firefox-esr and not for the standard version of Firefox. Could this be a bug?

I had exactly the same problem, with resistFingerprinting also disabled and the Date() only showing correctly on the Settings and Extensions pages.
Updating from Firefox 115 ESR to 126 and copying everything over from old profile to the new one resolved this, and now the timezone is correct everywhere.
